# Assign Domain names to devices in my network

Tags: dns

I need to set up domain names for devices inside my network, but I can't find how to configure this in my router.  I have found the following [guide](https://www.draytek.com/en/faq/faq-miscellaneous/miscellaneous.application/how-to-use-lan-dns/), but it doesn't apply to my D-LINK router.

Does anyone know more about D-LINK routers to be able to find the equivalent configuration menu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define the hosts within the OS because your router doesn't have the capability your looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the D-Link routers. If you need that functionality, get a Draytek router (because Draytek clearly supports it, as per your link)